# Logstash error message when using ElasticSearch output=>"Failed to flush outgoing items"

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems, logstash

Im using ES 1.4.4 and LS 1.5 and Kibana 4 on Debian.
I start logstash, it works fine for a couple of minutes then i have a fatal error.
In order to shutdown logstash i have to delete the recent datas stored in ES, that's the only way i found.
One more relevant fact is that Elastic Search looks OK, i can see old datas in kibana and plugin head works fine.
My output config : output {  elasticsearch {port => 9200 protocol => http host => "127.0.0.1"}}

Any help will be appreciated :)

Here is the full error message :
Got error to send bulk of actions to elasticsearch server at 127.0.0.1 : Read timed out {:level=>:error}

Failed to flush outgoing items {:outgoing_count=>1362, :exception=>#, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.3.5-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:35:in initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:incall'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.3.5-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:61:in call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.3.5-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:224:incall_once'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.3.5-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:127:in code'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:50:inperform_request'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:187:inperform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:33:in perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:115:inperform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.7/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:80:in bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/protocol.rb:82:inbulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:413:in submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:412:insubmit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:438:in flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:436:inflush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.19/lib/stud/buffer.rb:219:in buffer_flush'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1341:ineach'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.19/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in buffer_flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.19/lib/stud/buffer.rb:193:inbuffer_flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.19/lib/stud/buffer.rb:159:in buffer_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-0.1.18-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:402:inreceive'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:88:in handle'", "(eval):1070:ininitialize'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in each'", "org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:805:inflat_map'", "(eval):1067:in initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:incall'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:279:in output'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:235:inoutputworker'", "/opt/logstash/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:163:in `start_outputs'"], :level=>:warn}

Comment: elasticsearch has its own logs, try looking there as well...

Answer (score 0):

Your elasticsearch have surpassed storage and it is unable to write new documents coming from logstash, try deleting old indices and then

```
PUT your_index/_settings
{
  "index": {
  "blocks.read_only": false
  }
}
```

I hope this will work for you. Thanks !!